# Add field to Edit Account form in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm adding a field to the template customer/form/edit.phtml. I used this code :

```
<li>
     <?php 
         $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','code_magique');
     ?>
     <label for="code_magique" class="<?php if($attribute->getIsRequired() == true){?>required<?php } ?>"><?php if($attribute->getIsRequired() == true){?><em>*</em><?php } ?><?php echo $this->__('Code') ?></label>
     <div class="input-box">
         <input type="text" name="code_magique" id="code_magique" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getData("code_magique")) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Code') ?>" class="input-text" />                   
     </div>
</li>
```

This display a field with my "code_magique" attribute inside but when i try to modify this attribute, it doesn't work, did I forget something?

Comment: to which part of magento account dashboard are you adding this input?

Comment: The "account information" one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick look at AccountController.php, and it seems there is some postprocessing of form data, not the simple `$model->addData($post);`

Try hooking to `customer_save_before` event and adding your data manually.

Hopefully you know how to create anobserver and add data to model object?

Comment: I know how to create an Observer. To get the input data I need to rewrite the AccountController editPostAction() method ? If you can help me for this part that would be nice ><

Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: No you don't. Yout just create an observer on `customer_save_before` , collect the data model (standard function of an observer) and do something like `$model->setData('my_stuff',Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam("my_stuff"))` and that's it